# jQuery , json data call doesnt work

Tags: jquery, json, each, getjson

Here is a sample of my code:

events.json // This file is in an external page

```
[
    {'id':1,'name':'george'},
    {'id':2,'name':'john'},
    {'id':3,'name':'nick'}
]
```

The json call:

```
$.getJSON('events.json', function(data) {
    $(data).each(function(i,val) {
        alert(data[i].name);
    });
});
```

Comment: give the external link then it would be much easieer

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid. Identifiers and values must use double quotes not single quotes. jQuery is not able to parse the JSON and so your callback will not be executed.

Avoid manually creating JSON. Whatever programming language you use to produce the JSON, always use the relevant library to build the JSON.

You can validate your JSON at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).